# Handle user number input value condition with ReadOnly false of numericUpDown

Tags: c#, event-handling, readonly, numericupdown

In C# WinForms desktop application I use 2 interdependent `numericUpDown1` `min` and `numericUpDown2` `max` value `numericUpDown` controls:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (numericUpDown1.Value <= numericUpDown2.Value)
    {
        min = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    } 
    else
    {
        numericUpDown1.Value = min - 1;
    }
}

private void numericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (numericUpDown2.Value >= numericUpDown1.Value)
    {
        max = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        numericUpDown2.Value = max + 1;
    }
}
```

with using of `ReadOnly = true;` to avoid making the maximal number less than minimal manually from `numericUpDown` input.:

```
        min = 20;
        max = 1999;

        numericUpDown1.Value = min;
        numericUpDown2.Value = max;

        numericUpDown1.ReadOnly = true;
        numericUpDown2.ReadOnly = true;

        numericUpDown1.Increment = 1;
        numericUpDown2.Increment = 1;

        numericUpDown1.Maximum = 2000;
        numericUpDown1.Minimum = 1;
        numericUpDown2.Maximum = 2000;
        numericUpDown2.Minimum = 1;
```

but I use a big range from 1 to 2000, and want to allow the user to change the number of `numericUpDown` manually with `ReadOnly = false;`.

I'm trying to figure out, how to control the user input condition with `ReadOnly = false;` of `numericUpDown` to avoid the input of maximal number less than minimal or minimal bigger then maximal.

Comment: hmmm but it will changed to min / max value on lost focus ... where is the problem ? Just use `Minimum`  and `Maximum` properties

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution:**

First of all Set your numericUpDown property ReadOnly=false or write a line of code in your FormLoad_Function,

```
numericUpDown1.ReadOnly = false;
numericUpDown2.ReadOnly = false;
```

Then

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (numericUpDown1.Value > numericUpDown2.Value)
    {
        numericUpDown1.Value = numericUpDown1.Value - 1;
        MessageBox.Show("Min value always less then Max value");
    } 
}

private void numericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (numericUpDown1.Value > numericUpDown2.Value)
    {
        numericUpDown2.Value = numericUpDown2.Value + 1;
        MessageBox.Show("Max value always greater then Min value");
    } 
}
```